# How to broadcast an NumPy array into a section of another NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have these arrays.

```
 a = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]])
 b = np.array([-1, -2, -3])
```

I want to change the some of elements of `a` with the elements of `b` like so:

```
a = [[1, -1, -1],
     [3, -2, -2],
     [4, -3, -3]]
```

I tried: `a[:,1:]=b` but got an exception:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (3,2)
```

What is the correct way to broadcast `b` into `a`?

Comment: `a[:, 1:] = b[:, None]` make `b` (3,1) shaped

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks that work. I did try `a[:, 1:] = b.T` to reshape to (3,1) but that did not work. Why did it not work? Seem that `b[:, None]` is the way to transpose a row vector to a column vector.

Comment: @SunBear: NumPy's idea of a transpose is n-dimensional, not 2-dimensional. It reverses the order of an array's axes. When there's only one axis, this changes nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to treat `b` as a column, but the broadcasting rules will try to copy `b` into the rows of `a[:, 1:]`. That won't work.

Instead, transpose `a` and copy `b` into the rows of the transpose:

```
a.T[1:] = b
```

Comment: If the memory-layout of `a` is such that `a.T` is a copy, this won't affect `a`, right?

Comment: @Ehsan: `a.T` cannot be a copy. It's not like `reshape`. `a.T[1:] = b` is guaranteed to write into `a`.

Comment: It's the reshape after a transpose that makes a copy.  Still I prefer reshaping `b` so it broadcasts.

Comment: Thanks. Your approach works. Will your approach be more computationally demanding than @hpaulj approach given that the size of `a` is typically larger than `b`?

Comment: @SunBear the transpose (like slicing and most reshaping) is done lazily in numpy, only metadata are modified. The cost does therefore not depend on data size.